# MySQL: can I create two tables with the same data field

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create two comments table one `saveJournal` and one `publishJournal`when the user log in they will be able to enter some data when they click save the data will be saved in the database and he/she will be the only one who can see the data if they click publish journal the journal will be published on the web and everyone will be able to see it.The data will not be removed form saveJournal in case the user want edit and update their data in both saveJournal & publishJournal. My question is does this way of creating two tables considered good way to design database or is there a way that I can do the same things without creating two tables with the same filed

Comment: Why not have one table that has a column(field) to indicate the type (assuming all columns(fields) are the same in both). Perhaps you could then literally just flip Save to Publish by changing the 1 column.

Comment: do you mean I should add one column that can store string "save" or string "publish" and check if it publish then show the data  for public ?

Comment: Close. However rather than string I'd suggest a boolean as you only have two types so false could represent save and true publish or vice-versa. If you want to cater for more types then integer could be used. String would work though.

Comment: oh I see thank you I don't know why I haven't thought of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two tables, you can use extra column `published` with values 0/1 or `status` with more values.

In the described case two tables are not a good idea.